# Start xserver + Libreoffice with no GUI

Tags: command-line

I am wondering how to start libreoffice in tty8 from tty1.

I tried

startx -- :1

But then how do I lauch libreoffice?

Using the above command is it possible to chose tty9-12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.Go to tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), login with your username and passwort, type `startx` and you will be transferred in tty8. If you dont have/see unity launcher in tty8, launch Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and in Terminal type `libreoffice` and that's it - you have Libreoffice in tty8.

Comment: Is there a way to start libreoffice directly from tty1 without having to load a seprate window in the x server? If not its ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to start a X application from a tty to be launched in a already running X server (tty7).

You can achieve that setting using `DISPLAY`:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 libreoffice # just for the current command
$ # or to all the following commands.
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ libreoffice
```

Comment: Sorry the x server on tty7 is not running and i am trying to get it to run in its own seprate  tty to the full xserver on tty7